# how to style datetime input field

Tags: html, css

In [this](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/BazzdYJ) codepen I am using the datetime input type. Trying to style it so that it is the same height and is at same level as the inputs fields to its left and right. I tried line height and height but these do not seem to be working. What is the proper way to style the height of a input field of type datetime? Thank you.

```
<div class="container">
                            <div class="row">

                            <div class="form-group col-4">
                                <label>Name </label>
                                <div>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group col-4">
                                <label>Date Time</label>
                                <div>
                                  <input type="datetime-local" id="datetime" name="datetime">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-4">
                                <label>Test</label>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" style="padding: 1em;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line-height is working, it will push the edges of the input box up and down

Add it like this:

```
#datetime {
/*   height: 1rem; */
 line-height:33px;
}
```

or add padding(Well I think this is the proper way):

```
#datetime {
  padding: 4px; /* more or less */
}
```

and see at codepen: https://codepen.io/ppwater/pen/rNLLzqX

Answer (score 0):

Set the input to height 40px; and see how it looks

Answer (score 0):

```
#datetime {
  height: 38px;
}
```

**use bootstrap-grid system too.**